# URl redirection issue in Django 2

Tags: django, django-urls

I'm new to Django and trying to build a web app with the following structure. I need your help to understand what Im doing wrong.

[image]

The flow of the application is **shadesProductUploader.urls** will forward '' to **authSection for login** and after a successful login user should be redirected to **mainSection 'home/'**.

Urls.py files are

**shadesProductUploader.urls**

```
 from django.contrib import admin
 from django.urls import path,include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',include('authSection.urls')),

]
```

**authSection.urls**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

app_name = 'authSection'

urlpatterns = [
path('', views.login_view, name='login'),
]
```

**mainSection.urls**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from . import views

app_name = 'mainSection'

urlpatterns = [
path('home/', views.home),
]
```

and the view.py in authSection

```
def login_view(request):
next = request.GET.get('next')
form = userLoginForm(request.POST or None)
if form.is_valid():
    username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
    password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
    user = authenticate(username=username,password=password)
    login(request,user)
    if next:
        return redirect(next)
    context={'user':user}
    return redirect('home/')
return render(request, 'login.html', {'form': form})
```

after a successful login I get this error.

[image]

What Am I missing? Not sure why I see a Url of  home/ home/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update `shadesProductUploader`'s main section url like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
        path('',include('mainSection.urls')),
        ... # other urls
    ]
```

And change in mainSection urls like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('home/', views.home, name="home"),  # <-- added name here
]
```

And in view, use it like this:

```
if next:
    return redirect(next)
context={'user':user}
return redirect(reverse('home'))
```

Here, we have [named](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial03/#namespacing-url-names) our url as `home`. And we got the url using [reverse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse).

Comment: It worked, but now my ShadesProductUploader looks like urlpatterns = [
    path('',include('mainSection.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',include('authSection.urls')),
    
] How does it determine which '' follow?

Comment: You can read about it in documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/#including-other-urlconfs